# How to modify scripts section to exclude/skip scenarion with tag @ignore in package.json

Tags: npm, cucumber, package.json, cucumberjs

I need to run cucumber tests using puppeteer and chai but exclude that scenario that has tag @ignore.

This should be probably set up in package.json under scripts and "test" line. But I don´t know how...

Here is code

```
{
  "name": "cucumber-puppeteer-example",
  "description": "Example project on how to use cucumber with puppeteer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf build out && tsc",
    "build:watch": "rimraf build && tsc -w",
    "test": "cucumber-js --require \"build/**/*.js\"",
    "test:headless": "cross-env CLS_TEST_HEADLESS=false cucumber-js --require \"build/**/*.js\"",
    "test:local": "rimraf out && cross-env CLS_TEST_HEADLESS=false CLS_TEST_URL=http://localhost:4200 cucumber-js --require \"build/**/*.js\"",
    "e2e": "ts-node",
    "chromium": "ts-node ci-chromium-install.ts linux 641577",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -c tslint.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.1.7",
    "@types/cucumber": "4.0.5",
    "@types/puppeteer": "1.12.3",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chromium": "^2.1.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "cucumber": "5.1.0",
    "puppeteer": "1.14.0",
    "ts-node": "8.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "tslint-no-unused-expression-chai": "^0.1.4",
    "typescript": "3.3.4000",
    "unzip": "0.1.11"
  }
}
```

Anyone know how to put somthing like this ~@ingore to ignore all tagged scenarios here to package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate class with the name cucumberOpts.ts/ js like below:

```
{
"compiler": "ts:ts-node/register",
"projectName": {
    "tags": {
        "ui": ["@Ui", "~@Ignore"],
        "api": ["@Api", "~@Ignore"]
    }
}
```

}

and use this class in your package.json file like as below:

```
"scripts": {
"e2e": "cucumber-js ./src/test/features --cucumberOpts.compiler -f node_modules/cucumber-pretty --format json:cucumber-json-report.json --cucumberOpts.projectName.tags.ui"
```

}

Use @Ignore tag before your scenario which you need to skip and run 'npm run e2e' command from your terminal. This will consider all scenario's which are tagged wit @Ui and will skip all the features which are tagged with @Ignore. If you include both the tags for same scenario, that scenario will be skipped

Answer (score 1):

Add a before step to your hook and return 'pending'